# How do i show my textboxes values in cells?

Tags: vba, excel

My user-form includes few text-box that their values need to be showed in specific cells of the table. how do i print these values in the cells?

```
'add a new employee to the bottom of the list

'last_row = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Cells(last_row, 1) = Box_FirstName.Value
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Cells(last_row, 2) = Box_LastName.Value.Value
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Cells(last_row, 3) = Box_Adress.Value.Value
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Cells(last_row, 4) = Box_ID.Value.Value
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as you show in your code:

```
Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Value
```

Just make sure that none of the variables you use to adress the cells are set to 0.

**Edit**
If you use Box_FirstName as String variable and change the UserFrom somethimes then:

```
Dim Form_Name as Object

Set Form_Name = UserForm1   'UserFrom name
Cells(1, 1) = Form_Name.Controls(Box_FistName).Value
```

Comment: Better also adding the `Form_Name` before the TextBox name if having multiple user forms

Comment: I meant as a String variable, sorry, forgot that part.